# DataGrip - aliases in uppercase

Tags: postgresql, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to set all aliases to uppercase in DataGrip SQL editor. I'm already using alias, but it's always set to lowercase, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM public.call_center cc
```

I want to set like:

```
SELECT * FROM public.call_center CC
```

Comment: You need to use `"CC"`

Answer (score 1):

Resolved: Just search to "word case" in settings and set alias to uppercase